# Limit of indicator function $1\{s\le z_n\}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{z_n\}$ be a sequence of reals converging to $z\in\mathbb R$. Is it true that $1_{(-\infty, z_n]}\to 1_{(-\infty, z]}$ a.e.? (depending on $z_n$, $1_{(-\infty, z_n]}(z)$ may converge to $1$, $0$, or may not converge at all, e.g for $z_n=z+(-1)^n/n$.)

Comment: What have you tried?  You know it does not necessarily work at the point $x=z$, so, can you test other points $x \neq z$?

Comment: @Michael: It works for other points. I'm just verifying someone else's solution, which argues that the indicator converges to either $1_{(-\infty,z)}$ or $1_{(-\infty,z]}$. And it seems to be incorrect...

Comment: I assume here that $1_{(-\infty, k]}(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1 & \mbox{if $x \in (-\infty, k]$}\\ 0 & \mbox{else} \end{array}\right.$.

Comment: @Michael. Yes..

Comment: So, it seems you have answered your own question...yes?

Answer (score 1):

For any point $x < z$, we can find a value $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that all points in the sequence $(z_{n+1}, z_{n+2}, \dots)$ are closer to $z$ than $x$ (by defining a ball around $z$ that is too small to contain $x$ and using the appropriate definition of a limit). Hence, for $m > n$, $I_{(-\infty, z_m]}(x) = 1 = I_{(-\infty, z]}(x)$ and thus the indicator functions converge pointwise to the left of $z$.

Similarly, for any point $x > z$, we can show that there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall m > n$, $I_{(-\infty, z_m]}(x) = 0 = I_{(-\infty, z]}(x)$, and hence the indicator functions converge pointwise to the right.

Thus, for $x \neq z$, the indicator functions converge pointwise.

However, as you have noticed, the functions do not in general converge pointwise for $x = z$ since it's possible for the functions to bounce endlessly between 0 and 1.

Similarly, in general the functions do not converge uniformly (proof left to the reader).